# Android FragmentPagerAdapter Circular listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, circular-list

I want to create a `circular listview` in `android`, however I'm using/extending FragmentPagerAdapter and I want to check the item position in order to check the next item in `circular listview`.

I just want to develop a infinite listview which will repeat itself when the scroll ends.

My Code:

```
private class ListPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private String[] items={"Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4", "Item5", "Item6", "Item7", "Item8"};
    public ListPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment sampleFragment=new SampleFragment();
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("text","FragmentNumber"+i);
        sampleFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return sampleFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return items[position];
    }

}
```

How I can make the Item1 after Item8 to make it a circular listview?

Answer (score -1):

What about something like:

```
bundle.putString("text","FragmentNumber"+(i % items.length));
```

I didn't test it but I would say that it could work :D

Comment: Its just a dummy text showing on each fragment. nothing else.

Comment: Yes I got it but I think the modulo should do the trick. Does it ?